# How can i remove the outline of a button in a click EventListener?

Tags: javascript

the following is an Eventlistener for a button and I'm trying to remove the outline of the button among other things...

```
btn.addEventListener('click', boom)
function boom () {
    let input2 = input.value;
    document.querySelector('.btn').style.outline = "none" //THIS IS THE LINE
    if (input2 === '') {
        alert("You Can't Enter an Empty Value") 
        output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML; 
    }
    else {
    output.innerHTML = input2;
    input.value = '';
}
    }
```

but this line isn't working

`document.querySelector('.btn').style.outline = "none"`

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] showing the problematic outline?

Comment: I have made some edits... I have clarified which line isn't working in the last line of the question. hopefully, it's clear now

Comment: What do u expect with style.outline?

Comment: i want to remove the outline for the button
, basically this if the button is clicked `.btn {outline: none;}`

Comment: can u put also your html code especially your button code?

Comment: `.btn {
  background-color: #88d5e9;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
}` this is it

Comment: Works fine for me though `let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', boom)
function boom () {
    btn.style.outline = "none";
}`

Comment: hmmm maybe it's my browser then